# How to copy files from multiple source folders to target folders in azure data lake storage gen 2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I have multiple folders in ADLS and each folder have delta files in it. 
My goal is to convert all the delta files into parquet format, and place it in a different folder. And I want to maintain same folder names in target as in source.

I have written a script which takes in folder name as parameter, then converts all delta files in that folder to parquet and move to target directory with same name as source folder. Below is snippet of code.

```
var loadDelta = spark.read.format("delta").load(deltaPath)
loadDelta.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(parquetPath)
```

Here I have to define deltaPath(Source folder) and parquetPath(Target folder) for each folder...which is counter-productive if I have to scale it up for 100s of folders. I was wondering if there is a way that files of all the folders present in Source directory can be converted using the code and place in target directory in similar folder structure.

E.g.
This is the Source directory and it have 4 folder/tables. Each folder have delta files in it.
[image: SourceDirectory]

Aim is to create same 4 folder names in test directory(target) without providing any specific folder name as input, and use the conversion code to convert files to parquet format.

[image: DesiredTargetDirectory]

How can the conversion process be performed recursively. Any leads/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a DataFactory pipeline with copyData activities. 
You have just to define your data folders target in Source input (in copyData activity configs) and your target data folders in Sink with a Parquet format  (in copyData activity configs).

Comment: Hi. I used the datafactory pipeline but it simply copied the files in delta format. How do I define explicitly that the target files should be converted to parquet format. I tried changing the sink dataset property of compression type from snappy to none but then the pipeline failed with ErrorCode=ParquetNotSupportedTypeGeneric on Sink side.